# collect data for HashMap selenium java - what can be the xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

In the site this is how it looks City Name- Number of jobs
[image]

Site: `https://amfam.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/HomesiteCareers/4/refreshFacet/318c8bb6f553100021d223d9780d30be`

I was thinking of putting the name and corresponding job number in a HashMap, however the following approach which gets the city name and then job bumbers 1st, will not work.

```
 @Test
    public void visitSite() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //ToDo: Verify Locations Heading is displayed- should be Locations
        WebElement loc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2//span[@title='Locations']"));
        String locTitle = loc.getText();
        String expectedTitle = "Locations";
        Assert.assertEquals(locTitle, expectedTitle);

        //ToDo: Expand the More+ section of Locations title
        WebElement expandMore = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-metadata-id='locations']//div[@data-automation-id='wd-MoreLink']"));
        expandMore.click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        //ToDo: Collect City name and Number of jobs in HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> regionJobsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //This code below will collect City Names in an ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<WebElement> citiesL = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-metadata-id='locations']//div//label"));
        for (WebElement ele : citiesL) {
            cities.add(ele.getText());
        }

        //This code below will get City amd Job numbers and add to HashMap
        ArrayList<String> jobNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<WebElement> jobsL = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-metadata-id='locations']//span"));
        for (WebElement ele : jobsL) {
            jobNumbers.add(ele.getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
        }
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < cities.size() && j < jobNumbers.size(); i++, j++) {
            regionJobsMap.put(cities.get(i), jobNumbers.get(j));
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> mm:regionJobsMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(mm.getKey() +"  " + mm.getValue());
        }
    }

OUTPUT:
NJ - New Jersey  5
PA - Pennsylvania
```

Question: What would be a good way to Get the City name and corresponding job number? I cannot think of 1 xpath that will give me both. If I use separate xpaths then actual city and job numbers will not match. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What about this:

//div[@data-metadata-id='locations']//span[starts-with(text(),'(') and substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length(')') +1) = ')']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to store values in hashmap after you click on 'More' link:

```
    HashMap<String,String> hm= new HashMap<String,String>();
    List<WebElement> locations = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-metadata-id='locations']//div[@data-automation-id='facetValue']"));  //get list of locations
    for(int i=0; i<locations.size();i++) //iterate over list
    {
        String cities = locations.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("label[id*=CheckBox-locations]")).getText(); //get location name
        String jobNumber = locations.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("span[id*=CountLabel-locations]")).getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); // get no. of jobs in that particular location
        hm.put(cities, jobNumber);  // put it as key-value pair in hashmap

    }
    Set s=hm.entrySet();
    Iterator is=s.iterator();
    while(is.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry m= (Map.Entry)is.next();
        System.out.println(m.getKey()+"  =>  "+m.getValue()); //get values
    }
```

Note: Hashmap doesn't maintain any order. If that is the case you can use LinkedHashMap or use comparator to keep TreeMap sorted.